# iOS Delegate not called

Tags: ios, delegates

For a project I need to be able to send a status back from "secondTableViewController" to "firstTableViewController". I followed some tutorials on delegates but I don't seem to get it to work. When I want to call the method in firstTableViewController from the secondTableViewController I do a check to see if "delegate" property is empty, and every time it is..

This is my code:

SecondTableViewController.h

```
@protocol SendStatusDelegate <NSObject>
@required
-(void)didStatusChanged;

@end // eof delegate protocol

@interface SecondTableViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<SendStatusDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

SecondTableViewController.m

```
// Status is changed on row click
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (self.delegate) { // This is never called because delegate looks to remain empty
        [self.delegate didStatusChanged];
    }
}
```

FirstTableViewController.h

```
@interface FirstTableViewController : UITableViewController <SendStatusDelegate>

@end
```

FirstTableViewController.m

The only thing that goes on here is implementing the -(void)didStatusChanged method.

Comment: When did you set the delegate?

Comment: It's unrelated to your issue, but why are you doing `if (self.delegate)` at all? Just do `[self.delegate didStatusChanged];` without any if statement. If `self.delegate` is nil that will not cause any problems, you can send messages to nil in Obj-C and it happens all the time.

Comment: It is a good practice to check if the delegate is an initialised object and actually conforms the protocol, luckily you can do both with a single `self.delegate -respondsToSelector:` check. Removing such validation is a bad piece of advice IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First You need to set the `delegate` to self in `FirstTableViewController` when you init the `SecondTableViewController`. say on `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` you are calling the `SecondTableViewController` in that case,

```
FirstTableViewController.m

// Status is changed on row click
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    SecondTableViewController *secondTableVC = [SecondTableViewController alloc] init];
    secondTableVC.delegate = self;

}
```

Comment: The alloc/init was done in my prepareForSegue method (which is called from didSelectRowAtIndexPath). I Added the last piece of code to it and now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the `FirstTableViewController` where you create the `SecondTableViewController` instance you should assign the delegate of the created instance to `FirstTableViewController`

ie

```
secondTableViewControllerInstance.delegate = self;
```

in `FirstTableViewController`

Comment: Alternatively, use interface builder to set it.

Comment: Normally you can't set delegate of another VC at IB because its initialisation is out of the first VC scope, but doing that at the code is completely fine. What worries me is the capitalisation of the first character at ivar name, please don't give bad examples.

Answer (score 0):

Your `FirstTableViewController` Class should conform the `SendStatusDelegate` Like

```
@interface FirstTableViewController : UITableViewController <SendStatusDelegate>
```

And then then assign the `delegate` of `SecondViewController` instance by `self` Like

```
SecondTableViewControllerInstance.delegate = self;
```

Comment: I'm afraid the answer is misleading, you don't make the class to conform to protocol by adding `<ProtocolName>` part: it is only a declaration that, depending on the settings, may do or may not cause  build errors or warnings if the class doesn't actually conform the protocol (i.e. implements the required methods).